# Search on encrypted varchar fields in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, encryption, full-text-search

I have dived deep into this issue and have come up with some solutions, but I would like your opinions before I choose one.

Database: SQL Server 2014

I have three varchar columns `FirstName, MiddleName, LastName`.

I have encrypted these 3 columns, i.e. data within these columns is encrypted.

My application has a functionality for the operator to do a name search so that when the operation enters the `name` in the order `LastName FirstName MiddleName`, the database needs to search for it. The name would not be the exact match in these three columns - so a `like` query is required.

Because these columns are encrypted, you can not directly apply `like` operator on the concatenation of three columns. You would have to decrypt the values while concatenating and then apply the `like` operator - which will be just too slow considering the size of the database (~million rows). Also you can not index encrypted columns.

Second option is to not encrypt `LastName` (as any person can not be identified by just the last name) - have an index on `LastName` and then perform `like` query by decrypting and concatenating other two columns. I still feel that this is not going to work.

Third option is that, before `INSERTING` new row, concatenate the string as required by search `(LastName + ' ' + FirstName + ' ' + MiddleName)`, calculate SOUNDEX and then store the SOUNDEX in a separate column which can then be indexed and searched upon.

Can someone please shed some light on this and also suggest if you have any other different methods to search?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12258738/partial-search-on-encrypted-field

Comment: @PSK - I have gone through that question you mentioned above. I do not think that it is a duplicate of this. Different scenarios

Comment: Also, I believe that encrypting required individual fields protect data from a technical person accessing it using 'select' statements who is not authorized to see the decrypted values or do not have sufficient rights to perform decryption. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Partial search on Encrypted field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12258738/partial-search-on-encrypted-field)

Comment: @NayanAmbaliya You claim it's not a duplicate, but the only "difference" in your scenario is the names of the columns you want encrypted. The top answer there is extremely clear about what your options are.